# JTextPane make new line

Tags: java, html, swing, jtextpane, htmleditorkit

I can make new lines using this code

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  
sb.append("<span style=\"color:black\">--------------</span> <br>");  
sb.append("<span style=\"color:red\">Error." + e.toString() + "</span> <br>");
sshoutput.setContentType("text/html");  
sshoutput.setText(sb.toString());
```

but when I do this one more time with another text it only shows second text **not after this**

> Error." + e.toString()

Sorry my English is not great. I hope you understand.

Comment: Can you elaborate the exception a little bit with your code?

Comment: why is the StringBuilder object `br` but you're doing `sb.append`?

Comment: I don't really understand, unfortunately. Do you mean you want to add another text to the existing text, but that it replaces it instead?

Comment: sorry I writed it fast String Builder is sb

Comment: ^yes that's my question

Answer (score 3):

I'm working with JTextPane right now and what I do is:

```
JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();
StyledDocument doc = pane.getStyledDocument();
```

And so I can insert strings in any place using:

```
doc.insertString(STRING POSITION, STRING, null);
```

I have no exceptions with this method. There is also easy way to style letters using:

```
SimpleAttributeSet set = new SimpleAttributeSet();
//Here you modify set. Set is collection of
//various style instructions
//(letters color, bolded, italic, background color etc.)
//You modify set using StyleConstants class.
doc.setCharacterAttributes(START, LENGTH, set, true);
```

**EDIT:** An example, which creates text pane and writes in it styled 'Hello World':

```
JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();
StyledDocument doc = pane.getStyledDocument();
doc.insertString(0, "Hello", null);
SimpleAttributeSet set = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstans.setForeground(set, Color.RED);
doc.setCharacterAttributes(0, 5, set, true);
doc.insertString(5, "World!", null);
SimpleAttributeSet set = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstans.setForeground(set, Color.BLUE);
doc.setCharacterAttributes(5, 6, set, true);
```

Add it to a JPanel with GridLayout(1, 1) and you should see text pane with red string "Hello" and blue string "World" in it.